# ¿como tener una ventana JFrame una zona gráfica paintComponent y otra con JTextField, JButton y JLabel?

Tags: java

He buscado en Google y todo lo que encuentro en como construir todos esos apartados por separado pero ninguno muestra cómo tener en la misma ventana todo trabajando simultaneamente.
Como se puede apreciar en la imagen quisiera poder tener un area donde contiene campos de texto, cuadros de introducción de texto, botones que tienen acciones y una zona con gráficos.
No consigo entender cómo ponerlos todos juntos en el mismo JFrame.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

busca informacion sobre los layouts.Sirven para acomodar de cierta forma los componentes en la pantalla.Se pueden usar varias combinaciones,la que veo de primeras es en un JFrame establecerle un BorderLayout y que en el centro vaya el grafico (BorderLayout.CENTER) y en el de norte  los JTextField,labels y lo que quieras ponerle(BorderLayout.NORTH).